# SQL query connection in a Discord message event

Tags: mysql, node.js, discord.js

I have a database that stores a specific channel id, and I want to make sure that nobody sends a message in that specific channel. My current sql pool code :

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const pool = mysql.createPool({
host    : "localhost",
port    : 3306,
user    : "root",
password: "xxx",
database: 'db'
});
let sql = {};
sql.query = function(query, params, callback) {
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
 if(err) { 
  if (callback) callback(err, null, null); 
  return; 
}

connection.query(query, params, function(error, results, fields) {
  connection.release();
  if(error) { 
    if (callback) callback(error, null, null); 
    return; 
  }
  if (callback) callback(false, results, fields);
     });
   });
 };
```

And my current way of preventing users from sending messages is this :

```
client.on("message", async message => {
sql.query(`SELECT * FROM db_1 WHERE channelid = ${message.channel.id}`, (err, res) => {
if(message.channel.id == res[0].channelid) return message.delete();
  })
})
```

I'm wondering if this is a good idea as I have not taken into account there may be thousands of messages sent each seconds which means I'm going to be querying to my database thousands of times a second.

Is there a better way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Note : This is similar to most captcha bot that has a specific waiting room channel which new members are required to type a command like !verify to receive verification message.

Comment: Honestly, this would be very intensive on Discord's API having to delete the message everytime. - Talking from experience with this sort thing in the past.

Comment: Huh, that's a bit weird as most of the current server captcha bot is doing that

Comment: Badly made ones yes, the notable Server Captcha Bot [here](https://top.gg/bot/captcha) doesn't do that in any sense :)

Comment: Ah! That's interesting, I thought I remembered it doing that. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, Although a little tip, as I have made a captcha bot in the past avoid message deleting, focus moreso on the functionality of whether the bot itself can DM the user or not that way its more reliable to along the lines of Server Captcha Bot :) Happy Coding.